# Changing String Array Items based on if else statements

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, arrays

I'm using this string array as the listview array to display in a navigation drawer.

```
<string-array name="navItems">
    <item>Character 1</item>
    <item>Character 2</item>
    <item>Character 3</item>
    <item>Character 4</item>
    <item>Character 5</item>
    <item>Character 6</item>
    <item>Character 7</item>
    <item>Character 8</item>
    <item>Character 9</item>
    <item>Character 10</item>
</string-array>
```

I want the user to be able to change these items with the input of a name for each character similar to the way the title is changed to the respective character's name. (See below)

```
if (pref.contains("name")) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(pref.getString("name", "Character 1")); 
    } else {
        getActionBar().setTitle("Character 1");
    }
```

Is there anyway to change these array items programatically so they can be changed if the user has named the character?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you're trying to do. Me no understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify what `getResources().getStringArray(R.id.navItems)` returns. Those values are fixed. But you can store modified information in shared preferences

Since preferences are a key > value store, you'll need to define how your keys work. Just `"name"` isn't enough to store 10 different names.
A common approach is to define 2 arrays, one that contains keys, one that contains custom translated text. Both need to be of the same length.

```
<string-array name="navItemKeys">
    <item>char_1</item>
    <item>char_1</item>
    ...
```

Then save customized names under those keys. And to load the names array for your adapter you can do something like

```
String[] loadArray(Context context, SharedPreferences prefs) {
    String[] defaultNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navItems);
    String[] lookupKeys = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navItemKeys);

    String[] result = new String[defaultNames.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < lookupKeys.length; i++) {
        String lookupKey = lookupKeys[i];
        String defaultName = defaultNames[i];
        result[i] = prefs.getString(lookupKey, defaultName);
    }

    return result;
}
```